# Correct way to create a modal in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

***This question is about the correct way to create a general modal that using ReactJS, that will be used across multiple components in the application.***

Apparently, we have two ways to manage a modal:

1. Looking at libraries as react-modal(https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal) that utilizes the state to control the modal with a visible property and a close method.
2. As this medium article (https://medium.com/@danparkk/react-modals-scalable-customizable-neat-components-f2088d60f3d3) utilizing a state manager as Redux, Flux, ...

What is the "correct way"? Rewriting a state to a modal everytime you use in the application, or making an action to change in the state of the application every time?

Comment: It is depending if the modal is linked to a component (example: confirmation modal for suppression). In this case you can use the state of the parent for controlling its opening / closing. If you want to have a global modal you need to wired it with your store to control it.

Comment: I will edit, I mean a general modal that will be used across multiple components.

Comment: For my projects, I used a "dialogs" entry in the redux store; that is simply an array of what dialogs have been opened (referenced by a simple string label); that way it can keep track of them. When the close, it removes them from that array. At the top level (since my dialogs are needed over the top of all else and also more often than not are needed to be invoked from many places) I have a component that shows content in a modal when its corresponding label is in the redux dialogs array.